# Vanilla javascript Fetch API formData upload

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, fetch-api

I am trying to send form data to my API hosted on heroku.
On the API I had captured for empty input fields errors. It seems that I am sending data correctly (in my opinion). But I keep on receiving this error message which I know is a response from the API as it is a custom error:

```
{
    "message": {
        "typeofincident": "Type field is required"
    }
}
```

Below is my javascript code:

```
function postIncident(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
  let formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("typeofincident", 'typeofincident', document.getElementById('record_type').value);
  formdata.append("description", document.getElementById('description').value);
  formdata.append("location", document.getElementById('location').value);
  formdata.append('file', document.getElementById("media").files[0]); 
  fetch('https://issaireporterv2.herokuapp.com/api/v2/incidents', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formdata,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.Message) {
        alert(data.Message)
      } else {
        alert(data.Error)
      }
    })
}
```

The request payload is as follows:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryPoo9tZT7joBLu8YB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="typeofincident"


------WebKitFormBoundaryPoo9tZT7joBLu8YB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

theft
------WebKitFormBoundaryPoo9tZT7joBLu8YB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location"

Latitude: -1.2094403999999999 Longitude: 36.8949247
------WebKitFormBoundaryPoo9tZT7joBLu8YB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="user view.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryPoo9tZT7joBLu8YB--
```

Can anyone assist where I am wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The payload shows that `typeofincident` is empty, just like the error message says. If you look at the corresponding `formData.append()` command you should be able to spot the error.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `Content-Type` twice.

Once you claimed it was application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which it isn't.

Then you claimed it was multipart/form-data, but you didn't specify the boundary (`WebKitFormBoundaryPoo9tZT7joBLu8YB` … not that you can know what boundary will be generated for you) so it couldn't be parsed.

**Don't** override the `fetch` APIs generated Content-Type.